# GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT, CONCAT and how to select

Tags: mysql

I got three tables

```
objects     id, field1, field2, ...
groups      id, title, color
group_ref   oid, gid
```

So every object can be in n groups.

I want to show a list of objects and one field of that list are the groups an object is in. So here is what i came up with:

```
SELECT o.id,
CONCAT_WS("||", GROUP_CONCAT(gx.gid separator "|"), GROUP_CONCAT(gr.title, "#", gr.color separator "|")) AS groups 
FROM objects AS o 
LEFT JOIN group_ref AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid 
LEFT JOIN groups AS gr ON gx.gid = gr.id 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY o.id
```

That actually works and i can create the needed interface out of the (concatenated) groups field.

Problem is: How to select objects who are in one specific group only (e.g. gid=4)?

This only gets a part of the results:

```
WHERE gr.id = 4
```

or

```
HAVING gr.id = 4
```

Any help greatly appreciated! (maybe there is a more elegant way for the concat thingy too)

Comment: "is not working" is not an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get all objects in group 4 and all the groups those object are in. You want to JOIN on the group_ref table twice, once to filter (regular JOIN) and once to get the related groups (LEFT JOIN).

```
SELECT o.id,
CONCAT_WS("||", GROUP_CONCAT(gx.gid separator "|"),
GROUP_CONCAT(gr.title, "#", gr.color separator "|")) AS groups 
FROM objects AS o 
JOIN group_ref AS gfilter ON o.id = gfilter.oid AND gfilter.gid=4
LEFT JOIN group_ref AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid 
LEFT JOIN groups AS gr ON gx.gid = gr.id 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY o.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
WHERE gr.id = 4
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should display objects that are in one group only:

```
SELECT o.id,
CONCAT_WS("||", GROUP_CONCAT(gx.gid separator "|"),
    GROUP_CONCAT(gr.title, "#", gr.color separator "|")) AS groups 
FROM objects AS o 
LEFT JOIN group_ref AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid 
LEFT JOIN groups AS gr ON gx.gid = gr.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gx.gid) = 1
```

Comment: That looks interesting, but that gets me all objects which are only in one (1) group. I need to get all objects which are in a specific group (e.g. gid 4).